# Viewheight units in Electron inconsistent with Windows scaling on two different laptops with the same resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

CSS:

```
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }

    .example {
      position: absolute;
      width: 60px;
      left: calc(50vw - 30px);
      bottom: 20px;
    }
```

On my personal laptop and most laptops I've tested on so far (1920x1080 resolution), the .example div is positioned correctly 20px from the bottom of the window.

However my bosses laptop is shows the example cut off on the bottom of the screen. It's lower than it should be.

The body size is taller than the 100vh when Window's built in window scaling is enabled. He has the scaling set to 150%.

When I use the exact same settings on my laptop (1080p, 150% scaling), everything looks as it should.

Are there any other factors that could be at play here? I'm not sure what else I could be missing. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

edit: this is in an Electron based app that is fullscreen with no frame, if that's useful for anything.

Comment: Electron does not seem to work nice with windows scaling set to 150%. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8062

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an oversight on my end, and was actually an Electron issue (not css). I had a minimum window size defined that was meant to be commented out, so since there weren't enough pixels for the height of the screen the window itself was being stretched outside of the screen.